# Not able to get, modify and set Span text using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, dom

I am trying to remove £ from price and i need to do this using javascript 
same code working well in

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pc9z32vs/)

but not in live system

i am trying to do this using span and class but it is no working

https://caringforcare.co.uk/courses-4/payment/

ADD TO CART >> PROCEED TO PAYMENT  >>  Submit details

it will ask for user detail, you can put fake details

I am using below code to get "1 x £10.00 ex VAT"

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js'></script>

<script>
     var pay = $("span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount").text();
     console.log("pay ::"+pay);
    //pay = pay.replace("&pound;", ""); 
    //$("span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount").text(pay);
</script>
```

Please suggest what should i try.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

#### Why not? `pay = pay.replace("£", "");`

## Good approach

The best approach is putting that information into `data-attributes`.  This way, you skip that `replace` call, your data is hidden and available to manipulate it.

The parsed HTML never should be used to get information because is not suitable for data calculation, validation, comparison, Etc.

## Look at this code snippet

```js
var pay = $("span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount").data();
console.log(pay);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span data-currency='£' data-amount='10.00' data-quantity='1' class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">1 x £10.00 ex VAT</span>
```

The HTML has the right information for your users and the `data-attributes` have the data for calculation, validation, comparison, Etc.

Comment: and i don't have access to modify span tag, script file is separate and i have access to script file only

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?

```
pay = pay.replace("£", "");
```

My test:

```
const test = "1 x £10.00 ex VAT"

test.replace('£', '')
```

Output: "1 x 10.00 ex VAT"

Comment: it works fine in jsfiddle but not in live system currently using these code  var pay = $("span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount").text();
     console.log("pay ::"+pay); please try and check console it doesn't return anything

Comment: I have tried it on you live system. --- With $: TypeError: $ is not a function.
 ---- 
With jQuery: that works --
var pay = jQuery("span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount").text();
 ----  
console.log(pay): x £10.00 ex VAT

Comment: which browser you are using because it is not working for me in Firefox and Chrome

Comment: I use Chrome. 

To be sure, clean your cache after updating your js file.